# vim: Add clickable label

Tags: vim, hyperlink

I know that in emacs it is possible to insert some kind of "clickable text". I.e. you can insert a text, that, when the user presses enter on it, opens another file.

Is there something like this for vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but is filetype-specific. A best example will be vim's own help system that is nothing fancier than an unmodifiable buffer with specific mappings.

See [vimwiki](http://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/) and [vimorgmode](https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode) for examples to have such links.

Answer (score 4):

For simple ad hoc cases you could write a function to which opens a certain file based on the word under the cursor. You could then map this function to the double-click event.

For example:

```
function! CustomLoad()
    let word = expand("<cword>")
    let path = "/path/to/file/to/be/opened"
    if ( word == "special_keyword" && filereadable(path) )
        sil exe "split " . path
    endif
endfunction
```

And map it using:

```
nnoremap <2-LeftMouse> :call CustomLoad()<CR>
```

Thus double-clicking (in normal mode) on the word `special_keyword` will open the file `/path/to/file/to/be/opened` if it is readable. You could add multiple cases for different keywords, or do some text-processing of the keyword to generate the filename if required. (Note that the `filereadable` condition is not necessary, but probably a good idea.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is to write the filename and use `gf` to go to the file, `Ctrl+w,f` to open the file in a split window or `Ctrl+w,f,g` to open it in a tab. Note that the file must already exist. See [this vim wikia entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor) for some other tips.