# Associate one File to another File in linux

Tags: linux

We have application which is written in Python in linux enviromet which is legacy code.I have task to document which help other in wiki page. I thought, Can I add one file into Existing code. So I can add documentation into another File. So if user open file it will pop us with code detail. if user does not want to see that file they can close this File. for Example

sample.py ( A File which contain code)

demo.txt  ( which contain documentation file)

So if I open sample.py using vi like vi sample.py  than demo.txt open by default like pop us or simple way which contain documentation part. I think it is like windows tool when we open tool it pop us infront of user. it is my idea I am not sure really it is valid or not. I have searched but could not find any useful information.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is - do you want to automatically open demo.txt in vi every time sample.py is opened in vi?

Comment: Why not add a comment in your `sample.py` with a link to `demo.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do will most likely confuse the user. If one types `vi sample.py` one expects to read this file. Now what you can do as @HAL said in his comment is add a comment in your code saying that the documentation for this code is in the `demo.txt` accessible at /path/to/demo.txt.

I think this is the common way to do it, and you will probably frustrate the user if you don't do it this way. (at least I would be ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any Linux specific include functionality and I do not think that it exists, because the program you are executing is `vi` and not the Linux kernel. But editors support editor specific functions for hyper links. Here is an example for `vim`. [vim: Add clickable label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686115/vim-add-clickable-label)

Another way would be to replace `vi` with a shell script which does what you want. This is an example:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "sample.py" ] ; then
  vim demo.txt "$1"
fi
```

This will open the documentation together with the program in two `vim` buffers.